# Search all .htaccess files in a Linux server webroot for a word and return file paths to a text file

Tags: linux, search, grep, find

I have a Linux server and want to search all the .htaccess files in all the folders (public_html webroot and subfolders) that have a certain word (eg ldap) in it. I also want the file paths returned to these .htaccess files with the word in it and saved to a text file.
Can I do this with grep or find and what syntax is optimal.
I tried `find . -type f -printf '"%p"\n' | xargs grep ldap > /tmp/results.txt` but want to only search .htaccess files exclusively.
Thanks

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: That's a great idea +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your example, try using:

```
find . \( -type f -name .htaccess \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H ldap > /tmp/results.txt
```

this find will list null-terminated files .htaccess in . directory, and `xargs -0` pass them to the grep. `grep -H ldap`  will list files containing ldap string with filenames.

Comment: Thanks Maciej Wrobel